# Cannot Execute Binary File: Exec Format Error OOTP2015

Tags: execute-command

I am trying to install OOTP15 for linux.  I have downloaded the file and it is in my home folder.  When I go to execute the file I get the error message:

bash: /home/patrick/ootp15linuxsetup.bin.tar.gz: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

I am running the 32 bit version of Ubuntu and this download is supposedly compatible.  I am also admittedly pretty new to Linux as a whole so this is probably a dumb question.

Thanks!

Comment: tar.gz is an archive (like .zip). You first have to extract it, and inside you'll find the installer.

Answer (score 1):

Files with the *.tar.gz* extension are (supposed to be) archives, just like the *.zip* extension known in Windows. You have to extract them in order to use the content.

This archive will most likely contain an installation script, which you can then execute, or a deb package, which can be installed using the Software Center or the dpkg CLI.